# Icon as cell value using array formula

Tags: google-sheets, array-formulas, google-sheets-formula

I want an arrow icon (▶) in all cells in a column.  For a single cell I use `=char(HEX2DEC("25B6"))`.  How do I enter this as an array formula?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me the existing answer does not work, but this does:

```
=ArrayFormula(if(row(A1:A),char(9654),))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SUBSTITUTE(A1:A10&CHAR(HEX2DEC("25B6")), 0, ))
```

[image: 0]

---

**alternatives:**

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(ROW(A1:A10), "▶", ))
```

---

```
=TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(REPT("♀▶", 10), "♀"))
```

Comment: Almost perfect - would just need an if statement to avoid an extra arrow on the first line.  Good technique though.

Comment: @AndrewM. I didn't get the extra arrow... tho I added two alternatives... answer updated